# summarize in dplyr with the maximum value of the date - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data,

```
data

date           ID       value1        value2
2016-04-03     1          0              1
2016-04-10     1          6              2
2016-04-17     1          7              3
2016-04-24     1          2              4
2016-04-03     2          1              5
2016-04-10     2          5              6
2016-04-17     2          9              7
2016-04-24     2          4              8
```

Now I want to group by ID and find the mean of value2 and latest value of value1. Latest value in the sense, I would like to get the value of latest date i.e. here I would like to get the value1 for corresponding value of 2016-04-24 for each IDs. My output should be like,

```
ID       max_value1      mean_value2
1             2              2.5
2             4              6.5
```

The following is the command I am using,

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(mean_value2 = mean(value2))
```

But I am not sure how to do the first one. Can anybody help me in getting the latest value of value1 while summarizing in dplyr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be the following. My assumption here  is that `date` is a date object. You want to arrange the order of date for each ID using `arrange`. Then, you group the data by `ID`. In `summarize`, you can use `last()` to take the last value1 for each ID.

```
arrange(data,ID,date) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarize(mean_value2 = mean(value2), max_value1 = last(value1))

#     ID mean_value2 max_value1
#  <int>       <dbl>      <int>
#1     1         2.5          2
#2     2         6.5          4
```

DATA

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16894, 16901, 16908, 16915, 
16894, 16901, 16908, 16915), class = "Date"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), value1 = c(0L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
4L), value2 = 1:8), .Names = c("date", "ID", "value1", "value2"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Without arranging, you could alternately do `value1[which.max(date)]`, although that's not very dplyrish.

Comment: @Frank Sure thing. That will do too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,  .(max_value1 = value1[which.max(date)], 
                        mean_value2 = mean(value2)) , by = ID]
 #   ID max_value1 mean_value2
 #1:  1          2         2.5
 #2:  2          4         6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the function `nth` in `dplyr` which finds the nth value of a vector.

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
summarize(max_value1 = nth(value1, n = length(value1)), mean_value2 = mean(value2))
```

This is based on the assumption that the data is ordered by date as in the example; otherwise use arrange as discussed above.